# Access nextSibling when some inputs are inside parent elements

Tags: javascript, focus, nextsibling

I have a html table where some `<input>` are inside some `<td>`. I would like to focus the next input when current input has a value different from `""`. However this does not work since input elements are not directly following each other

```js
let cells = document.querySelectorAll('td > input');

for (let x of cells) {
  x.maxLength = 1;
  x.type = 'text';
  x.onkeyup = function() {
    if (this.value != '') { this.nextSibling.focus() } //HERE
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the `index` of the current cell and use that instead of the `nextSibling`.

```js
let cells = document.querySelectorAll('td > input');

for (let x of cells) {
  const index = [...cells].indexOf(x); // Get index of current cell
  
  x.maxLength = 1;
  x.type = 'text';
  x.onkeyup = function() {
    if (this.value != '' && cells[index + 1]) { // Check if the next cell exists
      cells[index + 1].focus(); // Focus next cell
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```